# Tangent Plane in the graph of $SL(3)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $SL(3)$ be the matrix $3 \times 3$ with determinant $1$.

$a)$ Show that $SL(3)$ is, locally, graph of a continuous differentiable function.

$b)$ Determine the dimension of the tangent plane for each point of this graph.

$c)$ Compute the tangent plane of the graph in the point $X_0 = Id$.

The first question I did, using the Implicit Function Theorem, and I found $g: U \subset \mathbb{R}^8 \rightarrow V \subset \mathbb{R}$.

The second, I guess the tangent plane has dimension $8$. But I do not nkow how compute the tangent plane in $X_0 = Id$.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the tangent plane of the graph $G(f)\subseteq \mathbb R^3$ of a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I know how to compute the tangent plane, but my function is in $\mathbb{R}^8$ and my point is $X_0 = Id$, a matriz.

Comment: Being a matrix is irrelevant. You can just see it as a point in $\mathbb R^9$. Then you can calculate the the graph $G(g)\subseteq\mathbb R^9$ of your function $g:\mathbb R^8 \to\mathbb R$, and do the same proccess to get its tangent plane at $X_0$. May you try to do this and then update your question with your attempt?